# Запуск exe с флеш носителя

Tags: c++

Компилирую exe, который необходимо запустить с флеш носителя на другом PC. При запуске, АВ Avast пропускает исполняемый файл через песочницу, говорит что угроз не найденно, и запускает exe на исполнение. Пробовал компилировать простое консольное приложение Hello world!, такая же ситуация. Как можно обойти этот момент?

Comment: Какой именно момент обойти? Компиляцию Hello World?

Comment: Вы тестируете дебаг или релиз exe файл? У вас статическая или динамическая линковка CRT?

Comment: что обойти подробнее? Или что то не работает программа? Или что бы не проверялось антивирусником?

Comment: Хотелось разобраться почему срабатывает АВ, и как можно этого избежать!

Comment: Заранее внести как исключение :) Или при распространении вируса нет доступа к настройкам антивирусника? :)

Comment: Вы точно не вирус пытаетесь распространять?...

Comment: Хорошая идея по поводу исключения! поробую найти в настройках Avast

Comment: @Unick Тестирую релиз версию. Как это может повлиять?

Comment: Вообще верный способ взять Dependency Walker и посмотреть все ли dll-ки у вас есть в системе.

Comment: @Unick так программа запускается и нормально работает! Интересно понять почему ее АВ пропускает через песочницу!

Comment: Она выводит какие-то ошибки, типа нет зависимых длл на той машине на которых вы свой exe запустить не можете?

Comment: @Unick exe запускается без проблем! хочу понять почему антивирус пропускает легальный файл через песочницу!

Comment: @chyond, антивирус скорее всего любой незнакомый экзешник пропускает через песочницу. По какому принципу он может определять "знакомость" - это уже другой вопрос)

Comment: @insolor спасибо! есть мысли по поводу определения "знакомости" файла Avast ом?

Answer (score 0):

Изменением настроек Аваста. Либо копированием файла с флешки на жёсткий диск.
Аваст по умолчанию считает все exe'шники на флешках недоверенными.

Comment: Почему все? Скачивал установочники программ из инета и они запускаються без песочницы! Пример установочник ваершарка.

Comment: @chyond, значит они заранее в белом списке как известные.